# Proof of $f'(x)+\alpha f(x)=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f\in C[a,b]$ be differentiable in $(a,b)$. If $f(a)=f(b)=0$ then prove that for any real number $\alpha$ $\exists$ $x\in (a,b)$ such that, $$f'(x)+\alpha f(x)=0.$$

Clearly,this is a problem of Roll's theorem. First consider the function $\phi (t)$
 such that $\phi$ is continuous on $[a,b]$
 & differentiable on $(a,b)$ & $\phi (a)=\phi (b)$ & such that $\phi'(t)=f'(t)+\alpha f(t)$. But I can't construct such a function. Please help on construction such a function $\phi$.

Comment: it is easy to guess $\phi(t)$ if you think about $e^{\alpha t}$ as a factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: consider $ e^{\alpha t}f(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible no such function $\phi$ exists. Let $f(x) = x - x^2$ on $[0,1]$ and $\alpha = 1$ for a counterexample.

Edit. Otherwise assume $\phi'(x) = f'(x) + f(x)$. Then 
$$\phi'(x) = (1 - 2x) + (x - x^2) = 1 - x - x^2.$$
Then 
$$\phi(1) - \phi(0) = \int_0^1 \phi'(x) \, dx = 1/6.$$

Therefore $\phi(1)$ and $\phi(0)$ can't both be zero, contrary to the requirement in the question.

Comment: Are you sure about this? There is a root (checked on WA).

Comment: I'm not disputing the original statement of the problem. I'm saying that the suggested method of proof can't work.

Comment: I just realized what you meant. My apologies. Good call on that.

Comment: Sorry..It was a typing mistake..It will be only $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$, not at all $0$.I just edit it.

Comment: Even so, it doesn't work. In Cameron Williams's answer, you have $\phi'(t) = e^{\alpha t}(f'(t) + \alpha f(t))$, and that works well.